# Java sort items by the same field twice

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a table of items (SQL Server), and each item contains a sequence number (which is not the id). The sequence can be 1, 2, 3, 4, etc ... The items table contains a "link" field and a "grouping" field. If item 2 has children, these children will have the link field filled with the id of item 2, and all their brothers will have the same grouping code. For example:

Table items

```
id     sequence     link        grouping
10      1            null        null
2       2            null        null
3       ..1           2           1
4       ..2           2           1 
36      ..3           2           1
4       3            null        null
25      4            null        null 
15      5            null        null
```

The table above is already ordered. I put the dots in the "sequence" column to show that they are children. I want to sort this way via java (obligatorily using Collections.sort), but I do not know how to do that.

EDIT: I tried this:

```
public class SequenceComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        String x1 = o1.getSequency().toString();
        String x2 = o2.getSequency().toString();
        int sComp = x1.compareTo(x2);

        if (sComp != 0) {
            return sComp;
        } else {
            x1 = o1.getLink().toString();
            x2 = o2.getLink() == null?"":o2.getLink().toString();
            return x1.compareTo(x2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using Java 7 or 8?

Comment: Shouldn't you have at least some Java code for us?

Comment: That means too us, you have a List<X>... can we see the class X that the list is serving as container__????

Comment: _"link field filled with the code of item 2,"_ Does the code refer to `id` of the table or `sequence` of the table. The example is little ambiguous

Comment: edited to better explanation

Comment: Basically, you can't do this without passing the entire collection, or at least a map of id to sequence and parent for the entire list, into the comparator. That is because when you compare two items, you don't have the information to tell you which is "bigger" without looking up through the entire parent list for each of them. I'd suggest doing a pre-processing and giving them a proper ordinal number.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: My solution couldn't work. I thought the "link" field held the parent record's sequence number, rather than its id. As @RealSkeptic said, this problem can't be solved with a simple sort.

Comment: So, how can I sort it?

Answer (score -1):

Supposing that you have a Item class, may it help

Implement a Comparator class:

```
class ItemCompare implements Comparator<Item> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        // write comparison logic here like below , it's just a sample
        return o1.getID().compareTo(o2.getID());
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
ItemCompare itemCompare = new ItemCompare();
Collections.sort(items, itemCompare);
```

If you are using java 8, you can do like this:

```
Collections.sort(items, (Item r1, Item r2) ->
r1.getID().compareTo(r2.getID()));
```